# Google Maps Android API v2- error while compiling my android application

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, android-maps, android-maps-v2

**Current Status: PROBLEM HAS NOT SOLVED YET- NEED HELP..**

Im now developing a map app by using the new google maps Android v2..Before I apply it into my real app..I did a testing..and tried to make it works..I followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) by Google Developers

But seems there are some part I missed, But couldn't find them.. Can u identify them for me? I willl give u my source code below...to let u see them clearly..

Here my current MainActivity class(updated): <---I have only this class in my program

```
    package com.madcatworld.demomapv2;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.map, fragment).commit();  

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Here is my activity_main.xml: (updated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Here is my Manifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.madcatworld.demomapv2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.madcatworld.demomapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.madcatworld.demomapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.madcatworld.demomapv2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

My emulator: a dialog "Get Google Play Services" appear..when I clicked it...a few errors occur as below..

my current error log(updated) it seems shorter than previous error!! :) :

```
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.d$2.onClick(Unknown Source)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-25 04:23:18.647: E/AndroidRuntime(503):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For your information,

1. I already generate a new api key in my google account by copy my
   SHAI num from eclipse..
2. I did this steps Android Tools> rightclick>  Export Signed
   Application Packages (to make them link each other, I create new
   keystore) My QUESTION IS: should I implement this (no 2)??

Please let me know if u found any mistakes I have made.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake you are trying to access `android.R.id.content` where in your `my activity_main.xml` file Mapfragment id is `android:id="@+id/map"`

So, try this way.

Put this Code in your onCreate(..) method

```
SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
```

instead of this.

```
  SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you Dixit Patel :) , already changed them..there still errors..i will update my error log..

Comment: can I just display the map without using support map fragment Dixil Patel?? I implement that code when browsing the solution yesterday.. I paste them there.. the class does not exist..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `commit()` use the `.getMap();` method to get and load the map.

> ```
> GoogleMap mMap;
>   mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
>                 .getMap();
> ```

Comment: Thank you Grishu.. :) Already changed that.. will update latest code soon and the error log.. Grishu... I dont have the SupportMapFragment class.. can I display the map without creating the class? even though in my MainActivity class consist the supportMapFragment command?

Comment: Grishu already did.. I remove the SupportMapFragement codes and implements urs...seems not working.. Eclipse suggested me to remove ur code.. :(